# Draw auto adjustable text infront of bitmap

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, google-maps-markers

i want to draw text in front of my marker image.but the text is going out of boundary of the image.can i auto adjust the text? If yes then please give me an example pragmatically.
i am using the following code to draw text.

```
    paint.setTextSize((int) (11 * scale));
    // text shadow
    paint.setShadowLayer(1f, 0f, 1f, Color.WHITE);

    // draw text to the Canvas center
    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);

    paint.getTextBounds(gText, 0, gText.length(), bounds);

        int x=20;
        int y=15;
    canvas.drawText(gText, x * scale, y * scale, paint);
```

it show the following output

[image]

how can i adjust the text?

Answer (score 0):

```
private TextPaint mTp;
private String mText;
private final static float TEXT_SIZE = 30;
private void drawingSettings()
{
mTp = new TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
mTp.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
mTp.setColor(0xFFCCCCCC);
mTp.setTextSize(TEXT_HEIGHT);

mText = "some text"
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
 int bmpWidth = mBitmap.getWidth();
 int textWidth = mTp.mesureText(mText);

 float textSize = TEXT_SIZE;

 while(mTp.mesureText(text)>bmpWidth)
 {
   textSize-1;
   mTp.setTextSize(textSize);
 }
 float xPos = 0;
 float yPos = 0;
 canvas.drawText(mText,xPos,yPos,mTp);
}
```

Note, when optimizing you should consider moving text size calculation outside the onDraw function.

Comment: it always show text of same size and not working for bigger text